# Overload operator =

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, equals, operator-keyword

I want to overload operator =.

That's my code

```
#define w 10
#define l 10

class grid
{
private:
    char battle_grid[w][l];
    [...]
public:
    grid();
[...]
    void show_grid();
    grid& operator=(const grid& ex)
    {
        battle_grid[w][l] = ex.battle_grid[w][l];
        return *this;
    }
}

grid::grid()
{
int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<w;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<l;j++) {
            battle_grid[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}
```

and when i try something like this in function main:

```
int main()
{
    [...]
    grid p1, p2;
    [...]
    p2 = p1;
    p2.show_grid();
    return 0;
}
```

it doesn't work and i don't know why. Grid p2 is empty.

Comment: Could you add the definition of the default constructor for `grid`, as well as the declarations/definitions of `w` and `l`?

Comment: you should add some more context for `l` and `w`. are these statements part of a loop?

Comment: Your assignment operator performs assignments only for one individual element of the 2D-array (the one at position `w,l` -- an invalid position). You need a loop there.

Comment: "it doesn't work"  is not a sufficient problem description.

Comment: If you just need the assignment operator to copy each class member (as you appear to want here), then you don't need to define it yourself. The implicit operator, which you'll get if you don't write you own operator or copy-constructor, will do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you aware that:

```
battle_grid[w][l] = ex.battle_grid[w][l];
```

doesn't copy the whole double array

Comment: indeed! i don't know why i forgot about that.